# selecting one column from 3 different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

```
Table 1: columns are: 

+------+-------+----------+----------+
| date |  time |  user_id |  channel |
+------+-------+----------+----------+

Table 2:

+---------+------------+
| user_id |  id _number |
+---------+------------+

Table 3: 

+---------+-------+
| channel |  sort |
+---------+-------+

In table 1 the columns are sorted as following : 
2011-07-29, 12:35:15.650, 22,  DeluxeMusic
In table 2 : 
130.83.10.c42ce82365b9f6d , 22 (same as user_id in table 1)
In table 3: 
DeluxeMusic (same as in table 1), entertainment.
```

The columns `user_id` in `table 2` :  `130.83.10.c42ce82365b9f6d` means a user_id of some user. From this user ID I need to get all entries with the value of `130` in the begining. For all entries with same value 130.

Then I need to seek for this value of `130` in the `table 3` the sort of channel they are watching, and to count by that all users watching a channel typ.

Channel typs are also : `sport, shopping, entertainment and so on`.

Comment: possible to provide more data ? i mean records ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this too:

```
select count(*) from t1 join t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t2.userid like '130%' join 
t3 on t1.channel = t3.channel group by t1.channel
```

sql fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7127d/1)

**Edit:**

another version:

```
select  count(t1.id) , t1.*, t2.*, t3.*
from t1 join t2 on t1.id = t2.id  join 
t3 on t1.channel = t3.channel and t2.userid 
like '130%' group by t3.channel, t1.id
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c36c63/4)

Comment: Since the query works, but I need the distinct users and distinct Channel typs not just the whole nr. of users... In order to get one entry of sport, shopping, entertainment and so on. instead of shopping, shopping ,shopping....., how can I change the query in a proper way?

Comment: I get a table with entries of all 3 tables. but each of the column with contant channel typ several times and not just one time. means: sport, sport, sport..... and not just one time. same case for user_id. I need it just one time, means distinct...how can I do it the best way?

Comment: a distinct on user id ?? may be that way you could get just one user id, but distinct will only work if the entire row has same values.

Comment: yes, distinct on user_id and on channel typ, and then to count all the distinct user_id, doesn't run

Comment: could u post in more records? so that i could try working on the query too??

Comment: I can send you a screen shot if you will send me an email to yanaigonen@hotmail.com. That would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get your question completely. But from what I understand you would be needing something like below:

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM TABLE1 T1,TABLE2 T2,TABLE3 T3
WHERE T1.USER_ID = T2.USER_ID 
AND T1.USER_ID LIKE '130%'
AND T1.CHANNEL = T3.CHANNEL
```

The above sql would be the used to fetch the count of the channels that the users with their use ids beginning with '130' would be watching.

Hopefully this should help you in someway.